# Start tomcat from eclipse, can't connect

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl

I am attempting to get tomcat running from eclipse. The tomcat installation I've got works for Netbeans, but I can't seem to get it to work from eclipse.  Here's server.xml (the latest iteration, anyway; I've tried various examples from the web for configuring the SSL connector, they all give the same result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on"
    className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by UserDatabaseRealm 
      to authenticate users -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />


    <!-- Datasources for Access Point Web Apps Realm -->
    <!-- DBCP Configuration -->

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIBusinessCenter" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIBusinessCenter;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIUserAdminDev" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIUserAdminDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APISalesPoint" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APISalesPoint;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APISalesPointDev" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APISalesPointDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/CarrierFootPrintsDev" password="aPassword"
      removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=jdbc/CarrierFootPrintsDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIQuoteCenterDev" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIQuoteCenterDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIRateCardDev" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIRateCardDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIRateCard" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIRateCard;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/CarrierFootPrints" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01p:1433;databaseName=CarrierFootPrints;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/Commissions" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01p:1433;databaseName=Commissions;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/AccCore" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=acc_core;" username="WebAppUser"
      validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60" name="jdbc/Lerg"
      password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=Lerg;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIMcDQuoteCenter" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIMcDQuoteCenter;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIMcDQuoteCenterDev" password="aPassword"
      removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIMcDQuoteCenterDev;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/API_Services" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01p:1433;databaseName=API_Services;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/Telemarketing" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=Telemarketing;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/Telemarketing_Training" password="aPassword"
      removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=Telemarketing_Training;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60" name="jdbc/SLM"
      password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=SLM;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/SLMTrain" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=SLMTrain;" username="WebAppUser"
      validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/SLMTCO" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=SLMTCO;" username="WebAppUser"
      validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="10" maxWait="60"
      name="jdbc/APIQuoteCenter" password="aPassword" removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="jdbc:sqlserver://sql01d:1433;databaseName=APIQuoteCenter;"
      username="WebAppUser" validationQuery="select 1;" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
      maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10" name="jdbc/resourcesDB"
      password="raj321" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resources"
      username="root" validationQuery="select 1" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share 
    a single "Container" Note: A "Service" is not itself a "Container", so you 
    may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level. Documentation 
    at /docs/config/service.html -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more 
      named thread pools -->

    <Executor maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4" name="tomcatThreadPool"
      namePrefix="catalina-exec-" />

    <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 80 -->
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
      disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" executor="tomcatThreadPool"
      maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443" />

    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
      keystoreFile="/conf/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit" maxThreads="25"
      port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true"
      sslProtocol="TLS" />


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1" name="Catalina">

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI resources 
        under the key "UserDatabase". Any edits that are performed against this UserDatabase 
        are immediately available for use by the Realm. -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
        resourceName="UserDatabase" />

      <!-- Define the default virtual host Note: XML Schema validation will 
        not work with Xerces 2.2. -->
      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
        unpackWARs="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications 
          Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />


      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Here's the server config page:

[image: server config page]

Here's the entire console output from eclipse:

```
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\local;c:\devTools\apache-maven\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.6\bin;C:\Windows\system32;;.
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1147 ms
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 08, 2016 9:17:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 535 ms
```

This is all I get:

[image: resulting browser page]

I've tried other addresses: http://localhost:80, etc., nothing gives me a page. I don't have any apps configured to run (any more). Can anyone spot what's wrong?

Comment: Is that server.xml from workspace metadata or tomcat installation? You have selected to use workspace metadata in eclipse, so I am guessing this server.xml is from eclipse workspace? Also, can you check the tomcat logs (catalina, localhost and manager) to see if there are any problems reported in there.

Comment: The server.xml is the one from the server in eclipse. I looked in C:\Users\rcook\eclipse\workspaceEclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs and in C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\logs - there are no logs in either location. I searched the entire disk for any filename containing "catalina" - there is no catalina.log anywhere on my C drive. Yes, the server is still running.

Comment: Well as you don't have anything that handles the webroot `/`, I guess, tomcat doesn't know how to handle the request and returns HTTP 404. When you start tomcat from eclipse workspace metadata, I think, you might not get the tomcat 'default' apps with that. I would suggest, add a dummy app (e.g. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/) and give it a go.

Comment: I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET; I put the WAR file next to ROOT in the eclipse directory where it seems to expect things.

Comment: Let me phrase that better -- I downloaded the dummy app war, put it in the eclipse directory next to ROOT, and got ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when I attempted to access it.

Comment: Add the war from eclipse IDE. Import the WAR in eclipse and then `Add/Remove Application`

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I don't know what war you are suggesting that I add.

Comment: This WAR https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/